# How to convert numbers in a character variable to Numeric in sas

Tags: sas

Can anyone help me to resolve this?

I have a very large raw dataset with a character variable that contains text strings along with numbers & dates defined in character format. Now I want to process the dataset and create a new numeric variable and populate values only when the text in the actual variable is either a number or a date value. Otherwise missing

RAWDATA:

```
ACTUAL_VARIABLE                              NEW_NUM_VARIABLE(Expected Values)
------------------                           ---------------------------------
ODed on pills threw them all up - 2006
Y
1                                                        1
5                                                        5
ODed on pills
6                                                        6
Less than once a week
N
N
2006-11-12                                               2006-11-12
```

Many Thanks in Advance

Comment: ACTUAL_VARIABLE                                           
ODed on pills threw them all up - 2006 
Y 
1 
5 
ODed on pills 
6 
Less than once a week 
N 
2006-11-12 

NEW_NUM_VARIABLE(Expected Values) 
   
  
1
5
  
6
  
  
2006-11-12

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Typically it's polite to also mention what you have already tried or researched.

Comment: This question is certainly answered elsewhere on StackOverflow. Try searching for `prxmatch` for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way to do it (if you know the specific date format) is to use the input function.
    09:27
    If put(input(var,??yymmdd10.),yymmdd10.)=var then its a date!

```
else if input(var,best.) ne . then its a number.

Otherwiseits a character string.
```

Comment: Thanks Jim. This worked for me, As I have the IS8601 format applied to it for all the date values.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't as straightforward as it first looks, so I understand why it would be difficult to search for an answer.  Just extracting a number is pretty easy, but when dates are included it becomes a bit more complicated (particularly when the format entered could change, e.g. yyyy-mm-dd, dd-mm-yyyy, dd/mm/yy etc).

One thing to note first.  If you want to store the new values as a numeric field then you can't show a mix of numbers and dates.  Dates are stored as numbers and formatted to show the date, but you can't apply a format at row level.  Therefore I would suggest creating 2 new columns, 1 for numbers and 1 for dates.

My preferred approach is to use the `anyalpha` function to exclude any records with an alphabetic character, followed by the `anypunct` function to identify if a punctuation character exists (this should identify dates rather than just numbers). The `anydtdte` informat is then used to extract the date, this is a very useful informat as it reads dates stored in different ways (as per my note above).

There are clearly some caveats with this method.

- If any numbers contain decimals then my method would incorrectly treat these as dates, therefore only integers will be assigned correctly.
- It won't pick up dates that contain the month as words, e.g. 15-May-2015, as the `anyalpha` function would exclude them.  They will need to contain numbers only, separated by any punctuation character.

Here's my code.

```
/* create initial dataset */
data have;
input actual_variable $ 50.;
datalines;
ODed on pills threw them all up - 2006
Y
1                                       
5                                       
ODed on pills
6                                       
Less than once a week
N
N
2006-11-12                              
;
run;

/* extract dates and numbers */
data want;
set have;
if not anyalpha(actual_variable) then do; /* exclude records with an alphabetic character */
    if anypunct(actual_variable) then new_date_variable = input(actual_variable,anydtdte10.); /* if a punctuation character exists then read in as a date */
    else new_num_variable = input(actual_variable,best12.); /* else read in as a number */
end;
format new_date_variable yymmdd10.; /* show date field in required format */
run;
```